# The image cannot be displayed because it contains errors (php)

Tags: php, html, sql, image

I would like to display an image stored in my database but I keep getting that error.

The image is stored in my database as longblob.
I upload it using this piece of code in ***upload.php***:

```
<body>
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="image" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="UPLOAD" />
</form>
<?php
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]);
    if ($check !== false) {
        $image = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
        $imgContent = addslashes(file_get_contents($image));

        /*
     * Insert image data into database
     */

        //Insert image content into database

        $insert = $pdo->query("UPDATE users SET image='".$imgContent."'"."WHERE id_user = ".$posts[0]->get_id());


        if ($insert) {
            echo "File uploaded successfully.";
        } else {
            echo "File upload failed, please try again.";
        }
    } else {
        echo "Please select an image file to upload.";
    }
}
?>
```

Then I try to display it in ***getImage.php***:

```
<?php

$id = $_GET['id'];
$query = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username LIKE :us');
$query->bindValue(':us', $_SESSION['login'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->execute();
$user = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, "User");

header ('Content-Type: image/png');
echo $user[0]->get_image();
?>
```

When I go however to ***/getImage.php?id=1***, I have the error

> The image cannot be displayed because it contains errors

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you using `addslashes` on the image? That will alter it and make it not usable. Since it comes from the user use parameter binding as you do in getimage to prevent problems

Comment: first make sure that you got a valid image blob value, then try adding `echo base64_encode($user[0]->get_image());`

Comment: Why aren't you using a prepared statement? `addslashes` is inadequate for SQL injection prevention, even less for binary data.

Comment: I removed now addslashes and used prepared queries instead. echo base64_encode($user[0]->get_image()); did nothing unfortunately. The blob value is also valid since I can view the picture by downloading manually from the database

Comment: Your code actually works for me. What exactly is `get_image()` doing? Hopefully not `stripslashes`.

Comment: I have a User class having all the attributes from the user table in the database so I can use fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, "User"). get_image() just returns the longblob that I uploaded in the user table

Comment: By doing var_dump(); die; on get_image(), I get this : https://ibb.co/cyfM7Kr

Comment: That doesn't seem to be a PNG file, but you are using "Content-Type" for PNGs. Chrome and Firefox seem to ignore it anyway, so that might not be the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: I added `ob_end_clean();` before the header and it worked.